# serve request from only a particular domain in html

Tags: javascript

I have a htm page say *localstore.htm* in a domain say *x.com*

I will be calling this htm file in the `iframe` in one of my jsps in *y.x.com* (asubdomain of *x.com*).

This htm file reads all the localstore data and posts back to caller.

I want to restrict serving the requests in the *localstore.htm* only to jsps from *y.x.com* only. Only my jsps from *y.x.com* should get localstore data.

How to do this? Basically I have to check the request origin and based on that take action in my localstore.htm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe with `document.URL` from the iframe then you can split the string that contains the url with the function with `.split()`

Comment: document.URL will give the url of my localstore.htm. Right? I want to know the url, from which the request came from i.e my jsp in the subdomain's url.

Comment: Maybe this: `document.getElementById("theiframe").src`

Comment: I'm trying to write and test somthing that check if the domain is the same

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing for ages, so I will be watching this question with interest.  The only option I've found so far is to check the HTTP_Referer header.  However, that is cleared by some proxies and anti-virus apps, and can easily be edited, so that's not really a solid option.

Comment: Is your domain: y.x.com or it could be even z.y.x.com?